# Live Chat Node.js Socket.io

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io, localhost, chat

What should I use instead of port 3000 and port 3001 if I want to publish my chat live?

It works fine on localhost but obviously I need to change these ports when publishing live. I've just started playing around with socket.io but this bit confuses me.

Comment: You will need a live node server. The ports are only used for local development, since you need to host both your client and server on the same localhost. In reality they both get their own unique url.

Comment: So, let's say I buy a url for the frontend, do I have to buy the server url for the backend?

Comment: Not just the url but also actual server space where the code can run. Perhaps you can try this out with a free node server such as `heroku.com` or `netlify.com` (if they are still free).

Comment: By the way I have managed to solve my query. I've publish the server folder to RENDER and the frontend on Netlify for now. It works and both are free.

Answer (score 0):

By the way I have managed to solve my query. I've publish the server folder to RENDER and the frontend on Netlify for now. It works and both are free.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).